# Selenium data with form data

Tags: selenium, http, selenium-webdriver, http-post

I thought that fields consisted in form data in http request are mainly used for forms, but I encountered that as the way of communication with REST server. Is there any way to add form data to selenium http request? Just for clarification, I see something like that in network communication and want to add that to my http request:
[image]

I'd like to do that in python.
My current code is simply:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

from seleniumrequests import Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.dummy.com")
```

Please help me!

Comment: Hello! What language are you using and what code are you currently using to make the request that you'd like to add that form data to?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! I use python. Also updated my question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to send data with your request call. Am I right?

Comment: @supputuri , yes You're right, but the point is, that this is not ordinary data attached to request but that is kind of form data, which I don't fully recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the request.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.dummy.com"
data = {"csrf_test_name": "", "id": "1","child_id":"","match_id":"4566"}
print(requests.post(url, data).text)
```